# YouCompleteMe no completion for source file in adjacent folder

Tags: python, youcompleteme

I have an example project:

```
test
    -src
        someClass.py
    -tests
        test_someClass.py
```

Contents of src/someClass.py:

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        print("I'm a method")

    def another_method(self):
        self.some_method()
```

Contents of test_someClass.py:

```
from src.someClass import SomeClass

def test_someClass():
    c = SomeClass()
    c.some_method()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_someClass()
```

From `test`, I launch gvim and open both aforementioned files in different windows (buffers).

When editing `test_someClass.py`, I don't get completion for `SomeClass` defined in `someClass.py`. If I copy `SomeClass` into `test_someClass.py` then I get completion for it just fine. So it seems that it's not automatically reading this adjacent folder. How do I resolve this?

(Note that c/c++ files work just fine for me.)

I have python-jedi 0.11.1-1 and vim-jedi 0.8.0-3 installed. I have installed YouCompleteMe as per the full installation instructions, with the exception of using the system provided Clang.